# Problem with \DeclareSIPostPower in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[inline-per-mode = symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\textrm{\textonehalf}}

\begin{document}

\unit{\W\s\rooted\per\m\squared\per\K} thermal effusivity

\unit{\m\per\s\rooted} sorptivity

\end{document}
```

The first unit for thermal effusivity compiles fine, but for the second unit for sorptivity I get dozens of errors.  There seems to be some problem with `\rooted`, but only in the second situation.

What is wrong, is this a bug?

Curiously, this code worked in the old version of `siunitx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the power needs to be a real number, here `0.5`, not text: `siunitx` can't do maths with `\textrm{\textonehalf}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151452/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-pygmalion).